# suggested edit queue: fixing for new rules

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

There's been a number of entries in the review queue the last few weeks:

1. Edits to (old) questions where the only edit is a shorter title to fit the new 150-character limit
2. Edits to (old) questions to fix tags (e.g. `sql-like` instead of `like`)
3. Trivial edits to questions that are old and have negative votecounts

I'm not sure what to do with these.  For older questions it seems particularly not useful, especially for secondary or tertiary tags like `like` where you will almost definitely have `sql` as an accompanying tag.  The edit isn't "wrong" but it seems trivial.

The title ones seem completely worthless, since nothing's wrong about the old questions (well, nothing more wrong than was already there.)

The edits to bad questions/answers (again for trivial stuff) seems also like something to be rejected.  The proposed changes aren't making any real improvement to these items.

In some ways it feels like the threshold for edits should be higher for older posts (perhaps that's a different feature request).  But in the above kinds of cases, are any of them ones that I should be blanket-approving?

Comment: I asked the person who was altering the 150 character limit to slow down and/or stop... [Users are not told why they cannot suggest edits from the review interface when they have too many pending edits](//meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/562033)

Comment: The like was probably prompted by the recent burnination request [Should we, \[like\], burninate this tag?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363750)